# Piping Log File to event viewer with EVENTCREATE batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, event-viewer

I'm trying to pipe a log file to event viewer.

I am able to output the log file correctly but can't get the new line (carraige return) working.

I've tried ^L and \n options with no success.

https://serverfault.com/questions/137493/eventcreate-with-multiline-description

Here's the original code

```
SET log=%TEMP%\%computername%.txt

Echo.=================== >>%log%
echo.%Date% >>%log%
echo.%Time% >>%log%
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set eventtext=
for /f "delims=" %%l in (%log%) do set eventtext=!eventtext! %%l 
EVENTCREATE /id 101 /l application /t warning /so "Something bad happened" /d "%eventtext%"
```

The output in event viewer looks like this

```
===================   Thu 05/25/2017   17:22:48.41
```

I would like it to look like this

```
===================   
Thu 05/25/2017   
17:22:48.41
```

Comment: What do you mean by `^L` and `\n` options? What string is eventually assigned to `eventtext` and what do you expect/want it to be?

Comment: `^L` and `\n` is what I found when trying to create multiline descriptions.  `eventtext` outputs the marker , date and time.  I updated my question with what i want my data to look like.  There are going to be other items in the log file, but for simplicity i just used the date and time example.

Comment: I believe that the `^L`/`\n` required is in fact a control-L or a control-J character, best assigned to a variable and then included using `%var%`. There used to be an undocumented dynamic variable, `%=ExitCodeAscii%` which could be coaxed to return some values, but this seems no longer to be the case in Win 10. You can get a `^L` into `var` by creating a file (say ctrLL.txt) containing 3 bytes, 0C,0D,0A hex and then use `for /f %%a in (ctrLL.txt) do set "var=%%a"`. That may yield the desired result...no guarantees!

Comment: Did you find a solution meanwhile? What I am specifically looking for is to pipe the command output to eventcreate with type depending on %ERRORLEVEL%, but special chars and quotes makes troubles.